# Get list of all JavaScript files being included on the Magento front end?

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I'm trying to write some code that bridges Magento with Drupal and I want a simple way of adding Magento's frontend JavaScript to pages served by Drupal.

To this end: how do I return an array of URLs to JavaScript files used by Magento on the frontend? Specifically, I'm looking for the default layout handle and the individual product page.

Thanks!

Comment: That will very much depend on the page. You can't just load 'the Magento frontend JS files', since the JS files are added to the page based on layout handles and will differ depending on the layout handles on the page.

Comment: @Cags That makes sense. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you pretty close:

```
$update = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
$update->load(array('default','catalog_product_view'));
$xml = $update->asSimplexml();
$js = $xml->xpath('//action[@method="addJs"]');
Zend_Debug::dump($js);
```

The xpath argument *could* be refined to `//action[@method="addJs"]/script` for core code.

Of course, there are other arguments which add JS files (e.g. `addItem`) which will require additional handling.

Comment: Good approach but it wouldn't help in case of `<update handle="handle_name" />` construction is used. I found 244 usages of this construction in frontend layout updates.

Comment: This seems to do what I'm wanting, despite the point that Zyava made. Adding "/script" to the XPath yields a bunch of NULL entries, so that doesn't seem to work. The full code I have now is as follows: `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/magento/app/Mage.php');
  $update = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
  $update->load(array('default','catalog_product_view'));
  $xml = $update->asSimplexml();
  $js = $xml->xpath('//action[@method="addJs"]');
  $libs = array();
  foreach($js as $script) {
    $libs[] = 'magento/js/' . $script->script;
  }`

Comment: I'll leave this open another day or two to see if there are any other approaches, but will otherwise mark this as the answer.